# How to setup auto sync to blob storage from local server using PowerShell but without using AZcopy?

Tags: azure, powershell

Looking for automatic SYNC mechanism to SYNC export files from local server to blob container. we are currently using AZCOPY which takes a hell of a time and manpower. We want to reduce manual work to save time in migrating data and setup auto data sync permanently either by power shell or by some other method.

currently using AZCOPY

Comment: You can use Powershell and azcopy together; can you share some examples of the commands you're currently running in azcopy and why you have, as yet, not been able to automate this?

Comment: we are using normal AZcopy and sync commands.. Can you share what are the powershell and AZcopy commands we can use to migrate data from on-prem to blob.

Comment: Can you share what those commands are? AzCopy works in Powershell, so just trying to understand what it is you're currently doing